# Integrate latest Instagram posts into Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-content

I want to feature the image and a link to our latest company Instagram posts within the footer of all of our emails. As the content will be updated no more than daily, I envisage calling an Instagram API within an automation and then upserting latest post info (title,url,imagepath etc) into a DE.

Has anyone attempted this type of integration and if so can they provide some example code?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Not yet, having some authentication issues when trying to re-display the image assets.

Comment: The solution I found was to use the tool fetchrss.com to generate an RSS feed of our Instagram channel. A HTTPGet call to pull the XML result into SFMC, before using a set of BuildRowsetFromXml calls to get the information via XPATH.

Once I had the data then looping through the results and upserting them into a DE was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you can retrieve the Instagram data with JavaScript, my recommendation would be to utilize a [**Server-Side JavaScript Script Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) to retrieve the Instagram data and store it in a Data Extension.  The Script Activity can be a step in the Automation prior to your email send.

Once the data is in a Data Extension, you can utilize one of the [**AMPScript Lookup functions**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/) to iterate and output the data:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
  set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
  set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
  set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

  Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

 next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

  No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Reference**

- [Server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)